# drag and drop multiple files onto batch file to process into the powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop Multiple Excel Files onto the Batch File and process each Excel Files into Powershell.
I have most of it down but the problem is I can't get the FileNames ONLY and Can't Pass the Variable "DroppedFiles" as an Array.

**Batch File**

```
@echo off

SET ScriptDirectory=%~dp0
SET ScriptFile=%ScriptDirectory%Tool.ps1

for %%I in (%*) do (
     set DroppedFiles=%%I
)
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%ScriptFile%" "ScriptDirectory" "DroppedFiles"
```

**Tool.ps1 Script**

```
param($env:ScriptDirectory=$args[1],
      $env:DroppedFiles=$args[2])

$env:ScriptDirectory
$env:DroppedFiles

# Get the Files that I ONLY Dragged onto the Batch File
$Input = Get-ChildItem $PWD | Where {$_.Name -match $env:DroppedFiles}
```

Comment: In your batch file, you need to enclose your variables in percent characters, . Also `%DroppedFiles%` will contain only one of your dropped files, (the last one it processes). You would need to invoke `powershell.exe` within the loop to run it against each one by one. To send them all at once, get rid of the `for` loop and pass `%*` directly. A PowerShell script uses zero based agument index, so the script directory would be `$args[0]`.

Comment: also, see `for /?`, especially the modifiers section. You can get the filename with `%%~nI` (or `%%~nxI` - depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your batch file as follows:

```bash
@echo off

:: Pass the full paths of the dropped files directly to PowerShell
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0Tool.ps1" %*
```

Rewrite your PowerShell script as follows:

```bash
# Get information about the dropped files via their full paths, 
# reflected in the automatic $args variable.
$fileInfos = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $args
```

The above simplifies your code and bypasses its problems, notably:

- Lack of double-quoting of paths that may contain spaces (`SET ScriptDirectory=%~dp0`)
- Inability to iteratively build a *list* of values in a single variable with `for /?` (this would only work with *delayed* variable expansions).
- Lack of enclosing the defined variables in `%...%` (`"ScriptDirectory"`, `"DroppedFiles"`)
- On the PowerShell side:

  - Using the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) for *custom* purposes should be avoided.
  - Use the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) *instead* of formally declaring parameters.
  - Don't use `$env:` (environment variables) as *parameter* variables.